# Attachments showing undefinded(nodemailer, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

This part was working but stopped.  Any ideas what I did wrong or did something change?  The attachments when log show undefined, or maybe something changed.  Email sends but the attachment isn't there.

```
// send mail with defined transport object
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
from: '"Email Email" <foo@example.com>', // sender address
to: "email@gmail.com", // list of receivers
subject: "Subject", // Subject line
text: "Some Text", // plain text body
html: "<b>Some Text</b>", // html body
attachements:[{
filename: 'report.xlsx',
path: 'reports/AM_Report_2031_951.xlsx',
}]
});
```

Comment: You sure there is a file at `/reports/AM_Report_2031_951.xlsx`. Also just try this out: replace key `path` with `filePath` (Not sure this would work)

Comment: Smacked me in the face when I tried your fix.  It's just the misspelling of the word attachment.  Thank you for looking at this and helping out.